# How to find out what my AUCTeX version is?

Tags: auctex

How can I find out what my AUCTeX version is? I have Googled this question to no avail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is contained in the `AUCTeX-version` variable:

```
C-h v AUCTeX-version RET
```

Comment: A partial explanation of the capitalisation is "AUC" = "Aalborg Universitetscenter" now [Aalborg University](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aalborg_University)

Comment: @AndrewSwann: cleaned up the text. ;)

Comment: @AndrewSwann - Yep, wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUCTeX): "AUCTeX, originating from the ‘tex-mode.el’ package of Emacs 16, was created by students from Aalborg University Center (now Aalborg University), hence the name AUCTeX."

Answer (score 3):

If you installed AUCTeX from ELPA (which I generally recommend), then `M-x list-packages` will give you that information (the good thing about this method, is that it works for all packages installed from ELPA).